# How to make a request in DRF that points to another API endpoint in same Django app

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

very quick question that is how to nest request in Django-rest-framework. I have end point A that I make POST on and want to make another request to point B in it's serializer perform_create method. This API end points are actually written in same Django application.

- Serializer for API A

  ```
  class ReadingCreate(CreateAPIView):

      permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
      serializer_class = ReadingCreateSerializer

      def perform_create(self, serializer):
          #HERE I WANT TO MAKE REQUEST TO POINT B
          serializer.save(user_profile= UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
  ```

I am familiar with library such as request but I hope there is a better way since, I also need to send token for authentication and I am like in same file. This problem seems simple but I clearly don't know how to do it properly.

**Update:**
To explain more, "request" should find a book based on the isbn that I send it through ReadingCreateSerializer. But first I need to find a book (Google API), then save it to my DB. This needs to be done because book model is independent of UserProfile object and Reading is not (has additional information). That is what my "request" does.

Of course this could be done with two chain requests from client but I don't want that.

- Serializer:

  ```
  class ReadingCreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      isbn = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=20)

      class Meta:
          model = Reading
          fields = ['isbn', 'notes', 'rating', 'start_reading_date', 'end_reading_date']
  ```
- What I tried based on the answer: part of view and part of serializer

  ```
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
      self.request.method = 'POST'
      serializer.save(user_profile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user), request=self.request)

  def save(self, **kwargs):
      isbn = self.validated_data['isbn']
      request = kwargs.get("request", {})
      request.data = {'isbn': isbn}
      post_book(request)
  ```

What I found is that I can't import views (in my example post_book) to serializers I guess that is not allowed by Django.

Comment: Why do you want to make a request at all, rather than just calling the method you want? What exactly should this request do?

Comment: I tried that but I need isbn field. Check update.

Comment: What is postbook here? Why you guess you cannot import?did you tried?if yes what is the error?

Comment: post_book is my function api view (my B point). error: ImportError: cannot import name 'post_book'

Answer (score 5):

This will execute your API class.

```
APIClassB.as_view()(self.request)
```

If you need to change request method

```
self.request.method = 'POST'
APIClassB.as_view()(self.request)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I also need to get cleaned field from serializer (update).